# Update Django model field when auth token expires

Tags: python, django, jwt

I'm using JWT auth in Django, I need to set a field in one of my models to false when the access token expires. Is there anyway to monitor tokens like that?

Answer (score -1):

jwt logic is not suitable for this at all and for this you must use token authentication

Becuse jwt not saving data in database and if you wnt to save it in database , it is better to use token authe...

Comment: I had the idea of using the token expire time in my model, would that make it stateful?

Comment: jwt's logic is based on the fact that you do not store any data on the server and do not consume any space on the server, and if you are going to add something, you are using the token authentication architecture, which is better than the default mode of toekn use auth... and not jwt